# How to upgrade system app

Tags: android, upgrade

I had developed an app and build in Device.Now i need to upgrade this,is this possible that user will get update information from google play if yes how? I'm confused about this..I have published update version of same app but user not getting notification of update. I have to upgrade this any how so please suggest me about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The users will automatically get an update. But you need to increment the versionCode in the manifest:

```
android:versionCode="1"<!--change to 2-->
android:versionName="1.0" <!--You'd update this too, but I'm not sure its necessary-->
```

When that is done you make a new .apk, upload it to your play account and then you activate it.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Warpzit, r u sure so lets i publish my updated app,Actually i'm asking because i want to know can system app will get update.

Comment: @Dipu If you do the things I specified users will get update. But you should take note, they wont get the update instantaneous... The next time their device does a "check for updates" on play your updated app will be on the update list.